# How to use javac 1.7 instead of 1.6?

Tags: java, exception, compilation, jvm, javac

I am compiling some java code using javac 1.6.

A large number of errors are generated for multi catch exceptions. This had no problem in java 7.

On running from command line I want to use javac 1.7 instead of javac 1.6 currently being used. How can I achieve it?

(JDK 7 is installed in my computer)

Comment: Just change your JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables to point to JDK 1.7 ?

Comment: What does your PATH environment variable point to for Java?

Comment: I am sorry. I dont have much experience. What is Path environment?

Comment: @user2756339 Please make it a habit to state your OS and its architecture. That does not leave us guessing and helps provide better answers quicker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have not mentioned your platform, I am going to assume you are using `Windows 7`. Here are the instructions on how to set the path and by extension change it:

Windows 7:

```
From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
Choose Properties from the context menu.
Click the Advanced system settings link.
Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
```

So, what value for `PATH` do you need to enter?
For me, it is: **C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin**
You are good to go.
Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

---

What if you are using an IDE like Eclipse ?

> Right click your project choose properties.    Select Java Build Path
>   -> Libraries, select JRE System Library, click Edit and choose whichever JRE or JDK you like. You can also add from this screen a new
>   JRE or JDK.

Source: http://www.javavids.com/video/how-to-change-jre--jdk-in-eclipse-project.html

---

What if you are using Netbeans?

> Step One
>
> In your Netbeans home directory (for example, C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0.1), open up the netbeans.conf in the etc directory
>   (C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0.1\etc\netbeans.conf). Step Two
>
> Theres a property called netbeans_jdkhome.  Change the value to match
>   the JDK you want Netbeans to use (for example, C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25). Step Three
>
> Save your changes Step Four
>
> Restart Netbeans

Source: http://davidwburns.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/how-do-i-change-the-jdk-home-for-netbeans/

*I know the OP is using command line but for the sake of completeness, I have added extra information*

Comment: I am glad I could help you. However, sayings *thanks* is considered spam. Use the +1 button instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the full path to it:

```
{path_to_jdk_7}\bin\javac
```

Comment: could you give an example? I am ending up with error "is not a recognized command"